# Why does paintComponent draw all shapes one by one?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, graphics

I'm working on java gui with socket programming.I'm drawing shapes on the client side with data from the server.
First I pushed the incoming data into the array and then tried to draw it.my problem is that I want to draw all the shapes in the list, but every element is lost after drawing. I want to draw all the shapes I don't want to see one by one.
    My code in client side;

```
  public void starteGame(String received) {

    Info.shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    String[] mParsed = received.split(" ");
    int width = Integer.parseInt(mParsed[2]);
    int height = Integer.parseInt(mParsed[1]);
    int x1 = Integer.parseInt(mParsed[3]);
    int y1 = Integer.parseInt(mParsed[4]);
    int x2 = Integer.parseInt(mParsed[5]);
    int y2 = Integer.parseInt(mParsed[6]);
    int randomShape = Integer.parseInt(mParsed[7]);
    Color firstColor = new Color(Integer.parseInt(mParsed[8]), true);
    Color secondColor = new Color(Integer.parseInt(mParsed[9]), true);
    boolean cyclic = Boolean.parseBoolean(mParsed[10]);

    Shape shapeEx = new Shape(randomShape, x1, y1, x2, y2, firstColor, 
secondColor, cyclic);

    Info.shapes.add(shapeEx);

    showShapes(width, height);


}

public void showShapes(int height, int width) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();


        PanelDraw panel = new PanelDraw(width, height );

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setBackground(Color.RED);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setLocation(0, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);


}
```

And another function is;

```
public class PanelDraw extends JPanel  {

private MyShape myShape;
int width;
int height;
// constructor, creates a panel with random shapes
public PanelDraw(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    setBackground( Color.BLACK );   
} // end DrawPanel constructor

// end method

// for each shape array, draw the individual shapes
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    boolean filled = true;

    for (Shape shape : Info.shapes) {

        switch (shape.Type) {
            case 1:

                myShape = new MyPolygon(shape.X1, shape.Y1, shape.X2, shape.Y2, shape.FirstColor, filled);
                break;
            case 2:
                myShape = new MyRectangle(shape.X1, shape.Y1, shape.X2, shape.Y2, shape.FirstColor, filled);
                break;
            case 3:
                myShape = new MyOval(shape.X1, shape.Y1, shape.X2, shape.Y2, shape.FirstColor, filled);
                break;
        }

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; // cast g to Graphics2D
        g2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(shape.X1, shape.Y1, shape.FirstColor, shape.X2, shape.Y2,
                shape.SecondColor, shape.cyclic));
        myShape.draw(g2d);


    }


} // end method paintComponent

}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Why are you calling `g2d.dispose();` for each shape? Besides that, do you realize that you're always adding just one shape to the shape list (`Info.shapes.add(shapeEx);`)? Do you expect to call `starteGame(...)` multiple times and get multiple shapes? If so you shouldn't reinitialize that list there ( `Info.shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();`).

Comment: sorry would be repaint and dispose comment line. I updated my question

Comment: 1) You were told in your last question to NOT dispose() of Graphics objects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55859165/why-cant-i-create-a-shape-on-jpanel Pay attention to all suggestions so we don't spend time repeating ourselves. 2) Not sure what you expect to happen you only ever add 1 shape to the ArrayList and you always create a new frame to display the shape. So the ArratList that contains the shapes needs to be a property of the panel that draws the shapes. And you then need a method to add a shape to the ArrayList.

Comment: I tried but it says :   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859)
 at serialclickgame.PanelDraw.paintComponent(PanelDraw.java:52)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)

Comment: The paintComponent() does NOT create objects. Its only function is to paint the objects already contained in the ArrayList. I said the "addShape(...)" method is a method of the panel. Check out the `DrawOnComponent` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). It shows how to dynamically add shapes to be drawn.